# How to replace all double quotes to single quotes using jquery?

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I need to replace all double quotes to single quotes using jquery.

How I will do that.

I tested with this code but its not working properly.

`newTemp = newTemp.mystring.replace(/"/g, "'");`

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Use double quote to enclose the quote or escape it.

```
newTemp = mystring.replace(/"/g, "'");
```

or

```
newTemp = mystring.replace(/"/g, '\'');
```

Comment: This is destructive replacement.

Comment: if anybody need to escape the single quotes inside and '\'' doesn't work try with text.replace(/'/g, "&lsquo;");

Comment: what is the meaning of /g?

Comment: @ParthSavadiya it stands for 'global'. It's a replaceAll, it doesn't stop at the first occurrence. [https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction#flags](https://javascript.info/regexp-introduction#flags)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `replaceAll(search, replaceWith)` [[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll)].

Then, make sure you have a string by wrapping one type of quotes by a different type:

```
 'a "b" c'.replaceAll('"', "'")
 // result: "a 'b' c"
    
 'a "b" c'.replaceAll(`"`, `'`)
 // result: "a 'b' c"

 // Using RegEx. You MUST use a global RegEx(Meaning it'll match all occurrences).
 'a "b" c'.replaceAll(/\"/g, "'")
 // result: "a 'b' c"
```

Important(**!**) if you choose regex:

> when using a `regexp` you have to set the global ("g") flag;
> otherwise, it will throw a TypeError: "replaceAll must be called with
> a global RegExp".